# How do I add specific values from one different table to columns in a row based off of values in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, distinct

In SQL Server I have 2 tables that looks like this:

```
TEST SCRIPT    'a collection of test scripts'
(PK)
ID   Description   Count
------------------------
A12  Proj/Num/Dev  12
B34  Gone/Tri/Tel  43
C56  Geff/Ben/Dan  03

SCRIPT HISTORY 'the history of the aforementioned scripts'
(FK)      (PK)
ScriptID  ID   Machine    Date    Time    Passes
----------------------------------
A12       01   DEV012     6/26/15 16:54   4
A12       02   DEV596     6/28/15 13:12   9
A12       03   COM199     3/12/14 14:22   10
B34       04   COM199     6/30/13 15:45   12
B34       05   DEV012     6/30/15 13:13   14
B34       06   DEV444     6/12/15 11:14   14
C56       07   COM321     6/29/14 02:19   12
C56       08   ANS042     6/24/14 20:10   18
C56       09   COM432     6/30/15 12:24   4
C56       10   DEV444     4/20/12 23:55   2
```

In a single query, how would I write a select statement that takes just one entry for each DISTINCT script in TEST SCRIPT and pairs it with the values in only the TOP 1 most recent run time in SCRIPT HISTORY?

For example, the solution to the example tables above would be:

```
OUTPUT
ScriptID    ID    Machine    Date    Time    Passes
---------------------------------------------------
A12         02    DEV596     6/28/15 13:12   9
B34         05    DEV012     6/30/15 13:13   14
C56         09    COM432     6/30/15 12:24   4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you describe the problem is almost directly as `cross apply`:

```
select h.*
from testscript ts cross apply
     (select top 1 h.*
      from history h
      where h.scriptid = ts.id
      order by h.date desc, h.time desc
     ) h;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked flawlessly. I had no idea that `CROSS APPLY` was even a function. This opens up a bunch of possibilities for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like this:

```
    select * 
    from SCRIPT SCR
         left join (select MAX(SCRIPT_HISTORY.Date) as Date, SCRIPT_HISTORY.ScriptID 
                    from SCRIPT_HISTORY 
                    group by SCRIPT_HISTORY.ScriptID 
                    ) SH on SCR.ID = SH.ScriptID
```